# UISearchBar moves below the status bar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I'm using pretty much straight defaults in my Storyboard, and when my UISearchBar is selected, it pushes the UINavigationBar out of the way, but goes 20px further and sits beneath the status bar.

Also of note, I'm using a PFQueryTableViewController from the Parse framework, but it shouldn't make that much of a difference.

Here's a demo video: http://d.pr/Ky7p

Comment: Have you used keyboardWillShowNotification to move the view?

Comment: It just seems like a cheap trick, plus you have to get the animation curve right.

There must be something missing, the search bar doesn't just slide under the status bar by default.

Comment: You are right. It cannot move by default. Is the search bar inside a scrollview or have you written any code to move the view?

Comment: Huh. That's weird, I went through and hit "inferred" on all the Simulated Metrics options in IB again, and it worked. Cheers anyway.